# Check if all inputs are not empty except one

Tags: vba

I want to check if on a form, if all input (txtbox and combobox) are not empty except one that I use for searches (that one is empty, when I'm not using it)

The name of the the txtbox is "txtPesquisa" - I use it for searchs

```
    For Each c In Me.Controls
If TypeName(c) = "TextBox" Or TypeName(c) = "ComboBox" Then
    If c.Value = "" Then
            MsgBox "Preencher todas informações necessárias para agendamento!"
            Exit Sub
    End If
End If
```

Next c

Answer (score 0):

```
For Each c In Me.Controls
            If TypeName(c) = "TextBox" Or TypeName(c) = "ComboBox" Then
                If c.Name <> "txtPesquisa" And c.Value = "" Then
                    MsgBox "Preencher todas informações necessárias para agendamento!"
                    Exit Sub
                End If
            End If
        Next
```

Comment: You should add a check for `Control.Value` is null by concat an empty string : `c.value & vbNullString = vbNullString` where `vbNullString`is the vba-constant for `""` (Nz-function would work too, but only in ms-access).